# MVC3 : How to redirect to html page from a class which handles the errors

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect, razor

I have a custom Error Handler class attribute in MVC3 application. which takes `ExceptionContext` as parameter. I want to redirect to error.html page after writing the error log. 
I have tried as bellow but it does not work. Any suggestions please?

```
context.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Error.html");
```

**Custom Error Handler**

```
private static void LogUnhandledException(ExceptionContext context)
{
    var e = context.Exception;
    ErrorLog.Error(1, e.Message, e, "test");

    // Redirect to Error Page
    //context.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Error.htm");
    context.Result = new FilePathResult("~/Error.htm", "text/html");
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
    context.Result = new FilePathResult("~/Error.html", "text/html");
```

And i think you should do this in the `Error` `Action` not in the `HandleErrorAttribute` :

```
public ActionResult Error(){
   var result = new FilePathResult("~/Error.html", "text/html");
   return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi Wahid, I am not redirecting from Action. I need to redirect from a `Class` and method's return type is void.

Comment: Then do you use this `ExceptionContext` to show the `ActionResult` ?

Comment: `HandleErrorAttribute` automatically initialized if there is an exception happens inside Controllers. So inside `HandleErrorAttribute` I want to redirect it to Error.htm.